# How does the map function use its 3 parameters to reverse the order of values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone kindly explain what `element` in the map code refers to? I believe `idx` is the index of the array and `arr` is the array.

The goal of this function is to reverse the integers in the array. Can you please tell me how `arr[(arr.length - 1) - idx])` manages to reverse the order of the intenger in the array?

Please explain it in an elementary level so that I can understand how the parameters `(element, idx, arr)` achieve the goal of reversing integers in an array.

```js
function reverse3(array) {
    return array.map((element, idx, arr) => arr[(arr.length - 1) - idx]);
}

console.log(reverse3([5, 4, 3]));
```

Comment: The [MDN documentation for `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is good.

Comment: This explains what the map method does .https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

The `element` is the object at the specified index (`idx`) of the array (`arr`) as shown by [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

`arr[(arr.length - 1) - idx]` reverse the array because if you take any number (the size of the array) and subtract any other numbers from 0 to that number, you will reverse the order:

eg.:

```
size - idx = new_idx

8 - 0 = 8
8 - 1 = 7
8 - 2 = 6
8 - 3 = 5
8 - 4 = 4
8 - 5 = 3
8 - 6 = 2
8 - 7 = 1
8 - 8 = 0
```

The `-1` in the lambda expression is because the array is indexed from 0, rather than 1, so the above is actually an array of size 9 with the -1 already included.

Comment: Hello Draco!! Thank you soooo much. You broke it down for me really simply and nicely.  I suppose the ' =>' does not have any deep meaning right? It is just there as part of the map structure right?

Comment: In fact you did a much better job then the mozilla documentation, if I had to rely on just that, I would have never  gotten my question answered. Big thanks!!

Comment: @appletree `=>` denotes a [lambda expression](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-minutes). If you want to see some abuse of it, check out some [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132090/lets-play-rummikub/132187#132187).

Comment: hmm,  lambda looks complicated; I am still a young learner, I will stick with basic stuff.  Big thanks for the help Draco18s!!!